# Is there a way to use a hardware DAW controller for stream / broadcast mixing

Tags: daw, controller, streaming, broadcasting

Sorry if this isn't quite the right board for my question. I recently started live streaming from my home studio. I do gameplay, sometimes music, with friends added via Skype / Zoom. That means I have a bunch of audio sources to monitor and mix for broadcasting. Currently, I'm doing this via the windows audio mixer, which isn't great. Now, I have an Icon Qcon Pro X DAW controller and two Qcon Pro XS extensions on my desk, which means I have 25 motorfaders and a beautiful meter bridge right in front of me. However I can't do anything with them outside of a DAW.

There has to be some creative way to turn that stuff into a broadcasting console, right?

So, my question is: Does anybody know of a windows DAW (that supports Mackie Control) or some other tool that would allow me to route the audio output from external programs into DAW tracks? So I could have one track for the game, another my mic, one for background music and one for Skype or whatever. From there on it should be smooth sailing with mixing and outputting. I just need to get the output from different programs as separate audio sources into a DAW. Maybe some virtual audio device thing like Soundflower on Mac? Is there something like that for windows? Any other ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: Nevermind. Found the solution in the sidebar. JACK Audio should do the trick. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have look to Voicemeter :

https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/index.htm

It manages streams between applications including ASIO applications (typically DAWs).

Comment: Voicemeter looks very interesting. Thanks. Will give it a deeper look.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this just in case someone is looking for something similar.

I found a great solution that does exactly what I wanted: Synchronous Audio Router http://sar.audio/

Works perfectly for me, plus it's free. It allows me to mix my stream audio in Cubase or Studio One, use my hardware controller and all of my VSTs, which is just lovely.